# Xamarin.forms how to get ID from image button?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.forms how to get ID from image button?

```
<ImageButton x:Name="quizButton" Source="quiz2.png"  Clicked="OnQuizClicked" />
```

I tried this way, but he throws me an error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
private async void OnQuizClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var button = sender as Button;
         var route = button?.BindingContext as Routes;

        var token = Application.Current.Properties["MyToken"].ToString();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("URL");
        List<Question> punkty = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Question>>(response);
        List<Question> list = new List<Question>();
        foreach (Question tmp in punkty)
        {
            if (tmp.RouteId == route.Id)
            {
                list.Add(tmp);
            }
        }


        await Navigation.PushAsync(new UserQuestionPage());
    }
```

Comment: you are casting `sender` as `Button`, not `ImageButton`

Comment: Can you please mark the right answer so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Okay, no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button) and [Imagebutton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton) are two different controls in Xamarin.forms.

You defined an ImageButton in Xaml, then sender in the Clicked Event should be a `ImageButton` :

```
private async void OnQuizClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imgButton = sender as ImageButton;

    //...
}
```